# Install R packages on remote linux server via RSclient on a windows machine

Tags: linux, r, package, rstudio

We are using an R UBUNTU server in the cloud hosted by AWS to run our models on. I can connect to that server with R studio on my desktop with the RSclient:

```
library(RSclient)
c <- RSconnect(host="*confidential*", port = *confidential*)
RSeval(c, "require(RODBC)")
[1] TRUE
```

But when I try to install additional packages in the same way, it fails and it takes about 5 minutes before I get this msg:

```
RSeval(c, "install.packages('surv')")
Error in RSeval(c, "install.packages('surv')") : remote evaluation failed
```

Since that server is set up by a third party and I would not like to ask them any time I need an additional package, I would like to install it myself. I have no experience with Linux so I was hoping this is possible with R on my own machine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Best regards,
Tim